# Could not cast value of type 'NSAsynchronousFetchResult' (0x103e13388) to 'NSArray' (0x10435cf28) Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I am working through a Core Data tutorial and my code throws the following error.

> Could not cast value of type 'NSAsynchronousFetchResult' (0x103e13388) to 'NSArray' (0x10435cf28).
>   2018-12-29 22:54:17.619639+0700 demoCoreData[2670:247527] Could not cast value of type 'NSAsynchronousFetchResult' (0x103e13388) to 'NSArray' (0x10435cf28).
>   (lldb)

My Question is:

Based on the error provided what is the reason my application is failing ?

Here's my code that won't compile:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var txtID: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtTen: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtTuoi: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lblKetQua: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


@IBAction func btnInsert(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // tạo biến để connect giữa iphone với Manage Object Context
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext //tạo biến connect với db
    //insert new Khach Hang
    let newKH = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "KhachHang", into: context) //insert new object

    newKH.setValue(Int(txtID.text!), forKey: "id") //forKey = tên column
    newKH.setValue(txtTen.text, forKey: "tenKH")
    newKH.setValue(Int(txtTuoi.text!), forKey: "tuoiKH")

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Insert Success")
    }catch {
        let err = error as NSError
        print("Error is: \(err)")
    }

}

@IBAction func btnShow(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // tạo biến để connect giữa iphone với Manage Object Context

    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext // tạo biến connect với db

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "KhachHang")// tạo biến truy vấn đến table "KhachHang"

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false // có trả về những kết quả sai hay ko

    do {
        let results = try context.execute(request)
        print("Truy Van Success")

        for re in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(re.value(forKey: "tenKH"))
        }

    }catch {
        let err = error as NSError
        print("Excute err: \(err)")
    }
} 
}
```

Here is my *.xcdatamodeld file

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=18b1iJYz3jWAFkxYK2V4RrkxCTeWuR5yr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUWJb.jpg)

What I would really like to know, is how to investigate this on my own.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The error message is very clear. You have a `NSAsynchronousFetchResult` (the result of a call to [`NSManagedObjectContext.execute()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506834-execute) that returns a ` NSPersistentStoreResult`, but you're trying to force cast it to an `NSArray`, which it isn't. Read the documentation.

Comment: In for loop, the original code is like below:

    for re in results {
        print(re.value(forKey: "tenKH"))
    }

I tried that, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

From your code:

```
    let results = try context.execute(request)

    for re in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
        print(re.value(forKey: "tenKH"))
    }
```

The `execute` method you're using returns an instance of `NSPersistentStoreResult`. This is an abstract class. The `NSAsynchronousFetchResult` mentioned in your error message is a concrete subclass of `NSPersistentStoreResult`.

Next, you attempt to cast this to `[NSManagedObject]`, which is a different, unrelated class. The error you see happens because it's not possible to typecast an `NSAsynchronousFetchResult` to an array, because they are not related or even similar to each other.

It looks like you meant to use `fetch(request)` instead of `execute(request)`, because `fetch` returns an array of managed objects.

> What I would really like to know, is how to investigate this on my own.

I wouldn't mention it but since you asked specifically: This is something you'd resolve by looking at Apple's documentation for the classes and methods you're using. The `execute` method is documented to return something different from what your code expects, and the error message gives a big clue to the nature of the problem.

Comment: @tom_Harrington, thank you for your detail explaining! I am a  will follow your advice!

Comment: thank you again for your help. My problem was solved.